# Discord.js Multiple Commands

Tags: node.js, bots

how can i make multiple commands with the discord.js module?

code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '!hello') {
    msg.reply('Hello!!');
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

So, how do i make it so I can use multiple commands? Like !hi and !whatsup.
I hope someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: maybe `.indexOf()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resume your `if statement` with `else if()`

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '!hello') {
    msg.reply('Hello!!');
  } else if(msg.content === "!hi") {
    msg.reply("Hi there!!");
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

Answer (score 1):

as a temporary solution, you can use "else if()" like so:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client(); 

client.on('message', message => {
if(message.content === '!command1') {
    message.channel.send('working!'); 
    } else if(message.content === '!command2') {
    message.channel.send('working!'); 
    } else if(message.content === '!command3') {
    message.channel.send('working');
}
}); 

client.login('Your Token goes here');
```

a better solution is to set up a command handler. there are a lot on youtube, one is: https://youtu.be/AUOb9_aAk7U
hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

its really easy

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', async message => {
if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("hello")) {
message.channel.send("hola")
}
if(message.content.startsWith("hi there")) {
message.channel.send("hello")
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if() as a temporary solution but it would be better to setup a command handler.

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    
    client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("command1")) {
    message.channel.send("...")
    }
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("command2")) {
    message.channel.send("...)
    }
    })
```